# Offline maps for ionic mobile application

Tags: openstreetmap, offline

I am working on an Ionic app (Angular + mobile). This app needs to provide a (basic) map of New Zealand. The problem is that the map needs to be available while the phone is offline.

I have worked a lot with Openlayers and co on many projects over the years, but this is the first time that I need to have the map available offline.

What it is right approach? Can I create / download the tiles?

Sorry for the broad question, but I literally don't know where to start.

Any help welcome.

Comment: did you find any solution?? Working also with Ionic

Comment: No - still struggling with that problem